# Blender how to add local rotation keyframe

Tags: animation, keyframes

I made a car model and then I animated it. I found that the wheel are rotating wrongly in world space : [image: Car IMG]
Wheels are childs of car.

By researching I found that it`s somehow because the wheel are animated in world space.
So I think by changing it to local space ring will rotate correctly.

I tried adding armature and make wheel rotate with bones but it didn't worked for some reason.
And I also tried other keyframes of blender like Visual Rotation but it had same resault. And I'm looking for something like `Local Rotation` in `insert Keyframe` window.

blend file :  [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select all four wheels

[image]

Go to frame 1

Hit A here so that all gets yellow:

[image]

[image]

Hit X -> delete keyframes

Now hit I when hovering over delta transforms -> rotation

[image]

go to frame 150

enter -360*3 in x, then I to insert keyframe

[image]

result:

[image]

repeat that for all wheels and use z rotation of delta transform to drive the curve.

[image]